# SQLite Order by AM/PM Time in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Here are the times in string:

01:00 PM
11:20 AM
04:20 PM

I want the order it by time in SQLite.

In MySQL is can be done like this

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM coursesEntity ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(startTime, '%l:%i %p') desc");
```

I know it won't work in SQLite.

But is there any alternative to STR_TO_DATE in android SQLite?

or any other way to do this?

Comment: see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) and use the last form

Comment: There is nothing about AM/PM

Comment: i know, you are simply using wrong date representation  format, why do you want to store things like AM / PM in the database?

Comment: @pskink is telling you to use a different representation for your times. You should be using 24 hour time at the very least and then dealing with the AM/PM part at the edges of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by saying *Here are the times in string: 01:00 PM 11:20 AM 04:20 PM* and thus that the three values **01:00 PM**, **11:20 AM** and **04:20 PM** are stored in the **startTime** column then the following would order accordingly.

```
SELECT * FROM coursesEntity ORDER BY substr(startTime,7,2),substr(startTime,1,5);
```

That is you are utilising the substr function [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Core Functions - substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract the parts when sorting.

However, it is recommended that you store dates and times using one of the recognised datetime formats (e.g. **13:00 11:20 16:20** as opposed to 01:00 PM 11:20 AM 04:20 PM) as per [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions - Time Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Doing so can simplify matters as there is then no need to extract parts of strings.

For example consider the following table that has an extract column **better_startTime** that stores the same time but in the format HH:MM then you could use one of the folloiwng :-

```
SELECT * FROM coursesEntity ORDER BY time(better_startTime);
SELECT * FROM coursesEntity ORDER BY better_startTime;
```